# Route keycloak register button to Vue app

Tags: python-3.x, docker, vue.js, keycloak

I am using `keycloak` as authentication for my `Vue.js` app. I am trying to implement the user registration but with custom fields i.e some extra data, I need for user registration. Since I do not have expertise in Java so I am not willing to clone `keycloak` repo and make changes to it. The workaround I found was to move the registration flow to my Vuejs app.
Is there any way I can redirect the user to my Vuejs registration page as soon as the user clicks the registration button on the `keycloak` login page? I have passed the correct `client-id` and `realm-name` and have a `keycloak` instance running on my local via docker.

Here is my `keycloak` initialization code:

```py
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js'
import useStore from './store'

const initOptions = {
    realm: '',
    clientId: '',
    url: 'http://localhost:8082/',
    'public-client': true,
    'verify-token-audience': false,
}
  
const keycloak = Keycloak(initOptions)
function initKeycloak() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        const store = useStore()
        keycloak.init({ onLoad: 'login-required', promistType: 'native', pkceMethod: 'S256' }).then((auth) => {
            if (!auth) {
                window.location.reload()
            } else {
                console.log('Authenticated')
            }
            if (keycloak.token) {
                store.token = keycloak.token
                window.localStorage.setItem('keycloakToken', keycloak.token)
                resolve()
            }
        })
        setInterval(() => {
            keycloak.updateToken(70).then((refreshed) => {
            if (refreshed) {
                store.token = keycloak.token
                window.localStorage.setItem('keycloakToken', keycloak.token)
                console.info('Token refreshed' + refreshed);
            } else {
                console.warn('Token not refreshed, valid for '
                + Math.round(keycloak.tokenParsed.exp + keycloak.timeSkew - new Date().getTime() / 1000) + ' seconds');
            }
            }).catch(() => {
            console.error('Failed to refresh token');
            });
        }, 3000)
    })
}
  
// keycloak logout
var logoutOptions = { redirectUri : 'http://localhost:3000' };

function keycloakLogout() {
keycloak.logout(logoutOptions).then((success) => {
    console.log("--> log: logout success ", success );
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("--> log: logout error ", error );
});
}


export { initKeycloak, keycloakLogout }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make any change to Keycloak source to do this. The UI layer you see comes from the default theme in Keycloak. You can create your custom theme in which you would use the link to your own user registration. But there are some important points to be aware of:

- You should probably have your own application backend in which the new user's data would be validated and then it will call Keycloak's [REST API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/20.0.2/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource) to add the new user. Otherwise you can't just submit your Vue.js client data to Keycloak.
- Unfortunately the Keycloak's [theme implementation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_themes) requires you to code in FreeMarker template language
- Check if the new preview feature named [declarative-user-profile](https://www.keycloak.org/server/features) can solve your problem or not (you have to enable it on Keycloak startup)
- Regarding the theme customization, I recommend you to have a look at the [keycloakify](https://www.keycloakify.dev/) project
  There may not be an easy way to achieve this if you're not Java developer or have no experience with Keycloak before.